# MDM enrollment for Windows 10 - MS-WSTEP certificate enrollment

Tags: mdm

I am implementing my own MDM server using OMA-DM protocol, and am currently working on enrolling a windows 10 client to my server. I have successfully implemented the 'discovery service' and 'policy service' steps as mentioned in this link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn925031(v=vs.85).aspx

I am currently trying to complete the 3rd step i.e. the 'certificate enrollment'. As stated in the above link, the client sends me the Request Security Token (RST) message (which has a PKCS#10 certificate request)and from my understanding, I am supposed to send a root and client certificate back in a wap provisioning xml. However, on the windows 10 machine I get a message "Something went wrong...". The administrative logs in Event Viewer are of no use and have this message : "MDM Enroll: Failed to receive or parse certificate enroll response. Result: (Unknown Win32 Error code: 0x80180008)."

I have the following questions:

1) From reading around, i have understood that the client will send a hard-coded CN value in the PKCS#10 certificate request and it is the responsibility of the server to send a signed client certificate with this same CN. Am I right ? or is it up to the server to send ANY CN it seems fit provided that the wap has subject in the search criteria param ?

2) The wap provisioning XML has a parameter called "SSLCLIENTCERTSEARCHCRITERIA". What should this value ideally be ? As per my understanding it should be the subject of the client certificate i.e CN.

3) Any way I can see more detailed logs on the windows 10 client PC ??

Here is my WAP :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><wap-provisioningdoc version="1.1">
<characteristic type="CertificateStore">
<characteristic type="Root">
<characteristic type="System">
<characteristic type="B8E6A72180B04F64CB594AEFBFDF2F0997DB6FD7">
<parm name="EncodedCertificate" value="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"/>
</characteristic>
</characteristic>
</characteristic>
</characteristic>
<characteristic type="CertificateStore">
<characteristic type="My">      
<characteristic type="User">
<characteristic type="8C0765870005BC084563F0D359AE41177CEB4F1C">
<parm name="EncodedCertificate" value="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"/>
</characteristic>
<characteristic type="PrivateKeyContainer"/> 
</characteristic>
<characteristic type="WSTEP">
<characteristic type="Renew">
<parm datatype="boolean" name="ROBOSupport" value="true"/>
<parm datatype="integer" name="RenewPeriod" value="60"/>
<parm datatype="integer" name="RetryInterval" value="4"/>
</characteristic>
</characteristic>
</characteristic>
</characteristic>
<characteristic type="APPLICATION">
<parm name="APPID" value="w7"/>
<parm name="PROVIDER-ID" value="MDMServer"/>
<parm name="NAME" value="test"/>
<parm name="ADDR" value="https://dhruvesh.auth.hpicorp.net/services/oma-dm/ws/syncml/initialquery"/>
<parm name="CONNRETRYFREQ" value="6"/>
<parm name="INITIALBACKOFFTIME" value="30000"/>
<parm name="MAXBACKOFFTIME" value="120000"/>
<parm name="BACKCOMPATRETRYDISABLED"/>
<parm name="DEFAULTENCODING" value="application/vnd.syncml.dm+wbxml"/>
<parm name="SSLCLIENTCERTSEARCHCRITERIA" value="Subject=CN%3D0C59BAB0-AE47-449C-92CD-E122363!D37B7357741EF44EA285D0D6371F70AC&amp;amp;Stores=My%5CUser"/>
<characteristic type="APPAUTH">
<parm name="AAUTHLEVEL" value="CLIENT"/>
<parm name="AAUTHTYPE" value="DIGEST"/>
<parm name="AAUTHSECRET" value="password1"/>  <!-- Have a doubt about this field and the one below. Whose passwords and nonce do they mean? -->
<parm name="AAUTHDATA" value="nonce"/>
</characteristic>
<characteristic type="APPAUTH">
<parm name="AAUTHLEVEL" value="APPSRV"/>
<parm name="AAUTHTYPE" value="BASIC"/>
<parm name="AAUTHNAME" value="abc@abc.com"/> <!-- Have a doubt about this field and the one below. Whose username and passwords do they mean? -->
<parm name="AAUTHSECRET" value="Computer@2"/>
</characteristic>
</characteristic>
<characteristic type="DMClient">
<characteristic type="Provider">
<characteristic type="MDMServer">
<parm datatype="string" name="UPN" value="UserPrincipalName@contoso.com"/> <!-- Doubt about this field too. What is expected ? -->
<characteristic type="Poll">
<parm datatype="integer" name="NumberOfFirstRetries" value="8"/>
<parm datatype="integer" name="IntervalForFirstSetOfRetries" value="15"/>
<parm datatype="integer" name="NumberOfSecondRetries" value="5"/>
<parm datatype="integer" name="IntervalForSecondSetOfRetries" value="3"/>
<parm datatype="integer" name="NumberOfRemainingScheduledRetries" value="0"/>
<parm datatype="integer" name="IntervalForRemainingScheduledRetries" value="1560"/>
<parm datatype="boolean" name="PollOnLogin" value="true"/>
</characteristic>
<parm datatype="string" name="EntDeviceName" value="Administrator_Windows"/>
</characteristic>
</characteristic>
</characteristic>
</wap-provisioningdoc>
```

Have a few doubts in the above wap too (have put comments there).

Really stuck here. Any help would really be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the xml tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```

from the beginning since the WAP payload is not a full XML payload. Other than that you may run into an issue when generating the certificate from the PKCS10 payload. Make sure that you change the subject name to a value that you want and that you pass it down to the "SSLCLIENTCERTSEARCHCRITERIA" criteria. Otherwise, your device will register but will never communicate with your management server.

This may also help: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2013/10/03/common-issues-when-implementing-windows-phone-8-enterprise-mobile-device-management/

Good luck!